# SwiftUI MapKit region resets

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

Using Xcode 14.3 I have this basic code.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var buttonState: Bool = false
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.65, longitude: -79.37), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: [.all], showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))

            HStack() {

                Button {
                    buttonState.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: buttonState ? "location" : "location.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 96))
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Two problems with this

1. Manually panning the map in most cases immediately resets it to initial region center lat/long.
2. Tapping the 'Button' resets the map to the initial region center lat/long (if moved off center by panning).

I read posts about this error showing with the @Published 'region' object which is not the case here.  I'm also trying to understand what the button has to do with resetting the Map().  The same thing also happens if I add annotations to the map.  Every time the annotations array changes the map resets to the default region.

What is missing from this example to eliminate these behaviours?

Comment: By reset do you mean that it is following the user?

Comment: No. It resets the map to so user's location is in centre of the map.

Comment: AKA follows the user.

Comment: But if you look closer, then you'll see that the Button has nothing to do with location, or tracking the user or anything to do with the map at all (other than being the location arrow).  Why does pressing it resets the map so the user's location is in the centre of the screen?

Comment: From what I can replicate in your code the map is just following the user the button isn’t doing anything except for changing the image. Just constant following since you have following on. Maybe the code isn’t sufficient.

Comment: I updated the code to be exactly how I have it.  If I pan the map slowly so it doesn't automatically snap back to centre on user's location, and then press the Button, it centres on user's location.  Does the same if I pan the map quickly.  I show it in the link to youtube video further down...

Comment: Your best bet is to create your own follow functionality, the panning slow thing and it stop following seems to be a bug from my point of view. Everything else is as expected, the button triggering following seems to recreate the body and that is expected, that is how SwiftUI works.

Comment: I was watching this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/ and thought the way I have the Button wouldn't cause view update when Button is tapped.  As for creating my own follow functionality, I will give it a shot...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your example; the code provided works perfectly, and does not recenter when panning or when tapping the button (XC 14.3 iOS 16.4).

MapKit's Map view is capable of **automatically panning to 'follow' a user** as they move around geographically -- it's similar to the behavior you described:

> The map updates by following a user’s location. [[MapKit docs]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapusertrackingmode)

I suspect this is what you are seeing. As your GPS location changes, the map is updating. This is expected since you have set the userTrackingMode to use .follow.

Note that the simulator has a GPS simulation feature, with built-in routes or the capability of loading a GPX file. You can change or disable this feature in the simulator menus:

> Menu -> Features -> Location

To eliminate these behaviors, **change your userTrackingMode to .none** or disable the built-in GPS simulation.

Comment: You are correct.  I added a CoreLocation and locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization().  Now the problem shows as described in the OP.  I need to be tracking and displaying current user location.

Comment: So you want the user location to be visible on the map - but you don't want the map view to 'follow' this location? try using `showsUserLocation =true` and MKUserTrackingMode.none.

Comment: I want user's location to be shown while stationary and tracked while moving.  Code above does both.  Problem is when panning the map.  Panning quickly or pressing the Button resets the map so user location is in the centre of screen.  You can see it here: https://youtube.com/shorts/Oz0fVH4WtLc

Comment: Your requirements are not clear to me: In user tracking mode, the user location is at the center of the map. When you pan the map, it will be out of the center. Is your problem solved when you set `userTrackingMode = .none` as soon as a drag gesture is recognized?

Comment: For starters, i don't want pressing the Button to do anything to the Map.  Right now touching the button resets it so the user is in the centre of the map.  As you can see function of the Button has nothing to do with the map.

Second, if user pans the map quickly, the map immediately snaps back to show user in the centre of the screen.  Why? If I pan slowly, it doesn't do that and user's 'dot' eventually moves off the screen (which is fine).  It's in the video I posted.

Comment: The Map view will continually follow the users location as best it can, as long as you have `userTrackingMode = .follow`; it's not capable of following significant changes only. If you'd like to manage the map view's viewport yourself, turn off follow mode and update your `region` state variable when you detect a significant change in the users location; this will allow the map to pan freely, but will re-center it when a significant location change occurs. It may help to imagine your GPS location as a continual stream of data, always changing slightly and causing the Map to continually update.